# Rails paperclip resizing not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resize, styles, paperclip

I am trying to resize my images to 256x256 ignoring aspect ratio, so I used:

```
  has_attached_file :thumbnail, styles: { medium: "256x256!", thumb: "300x300"}
```

in my model, and in view:

```
  <%= image_tag guide.thumbnail(:medium), class: "guide_thumbnail" %>
```

but It fails to work. After changing to:

```
 has_attached_file :thumbnail, styles: { medium: "50x50!", thumb: "300x300"}
```

Nothing changes, so I guess It is using default styles? How can I change it and force to use my ones instead? Please help.

PS: After adding newly named style:
  `has_attached_file :thumbnail, styles: { medium: "256x256!", thumb: "300x300", hihi: "50x50!"}` 
It does not show any image - only its name. I checked the logs and that is the error message:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/guides/thumbnails/000/000/088/hihi/test300.jpg"):
```

What should I do?
And Additionally I am curious if setting the width of an image via css(for example width: 256px;) is a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

You can change into this:

```
has_attached_file :thumbnail, styles: { medium: "50x50>", thumb: "300x300"}
```

In my opinion, you'd better use image version properly with the real version.